# Как получить кординаты клика

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Всем привет!

Хочу получить кординаты клика пользователя, но нашёл только как это сделать через View:

```
int[] location = new int[2];
textView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли как то это сделать?

**UPDATE**
Нашёл это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773705/get-x-and-y-coordinates-onclick, помогло определять координаты в приложении, но мне нужно определить координаты в другом активити, как это можно сделать? Т.е. нужно получить кординаты из другого активити, но приложение одно и тоже

Comment: Т.е. ваш вопрос теперь о передаче данных меж активити?

Comment: Да, поидее да. Нужно отслеживать координаты кликов во втором активити, но при этом, во втором активити ничего для этого не предусмотрено

Comment: Передавать данные меж активити можно по разному. Например через [ActivityResultApi](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result). Или через паттерн наблюдатель (например в реализации через RxJava). Больше же всего меня беспокоит последняя часть вашего комментария. Что вам мешает написать во второй активити код опредления координат клика, раз он у вас уже есть? Может быть, активити - не ваша? Тогда всё довольно сложно. Но можно, если использовать инструменты для UI тестов.

Comment: Да, активити не моё

Comment: Боюсь, что если такое и можно сделать, то это очень сложно и, скорее всего, потребует root прав, т.к., по идее, если бы это можно было просто сделать, то это была бы жуткая дыра в безопасности. Каждый лаунчер мог бы считывать вводимые юзером пароли в банках, например.